Is there any topology of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the density $d(\mathbb{R})=|\mathbb{R}|$ and have the countable cellularity $c(\mathbb{R}) = \omega$?
I see that for the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$ there is a dense subset $\mathbb{Q}$ (and obviously there is no dense finite subset) so $d(\mathbb{R}) = \omega < |\mathbb{R}|$ and the supremum of cardinalities of families of disjoint open sets is countable $c(\mathbb{R}) = \omega$.
Then, is there any topology of $\mathbb{R}$ such that the density $d(\mathbb{R}) = |\mathbb{R}|$ and still have the countable cellularity $c(\mathbb{R}) = \omega$ ?

If you would like a Hausdorff example, consider the topology on $\mathbb R$ generated by sets of the form $(a,b)\setminus S$ where $|S|\lt|\mathbb R|$. This is a Hausdorff space of cellularity $\omega$ and density $|\mathbb R|$.
Assuming the continuum hypothesis and the negation of Souslin's hypothesis, a Souslin line provides an example with even nicer properties.

Here are some examples of the spaces that you are searching:
A particular example is the co-countable topology in $\mathbb{R}$.
Edited: In fact, if $X$ denotes $\mathbb{R}$ equiped with the cocountable topology, then it's clear that $X$ is not separable by the fact that if $U$ is countable then $\mathbb{R}\setminus U$ is an open set disjoint from $U$. Therefore, $\omega<d(X)\leq 2^\omega=|X|$. Using Continuum Hypothesis we can conclude that $d(X)=2^{\omega}=|\mathbb{R}|$.
For the cellularity, notice that if $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets in $X$ then $X=(X\setminus V)\cup (X\setminus U)$ and both sets are countable. Therefore, $X$ is countable. Absurd! Thus, $c(X)=\omega$.

On the last line by $d(X)$ you mean $c(X)$.

On the same line you write, inconsistently, both $\omega\lt d(X)\lt2^\omega=|\mathbb R|$ and $d(X)=2^\omega$. In fact $\omega\lt d(X)=\aleph_1\le2^\omega=|\mathbb R|$ since every uncountable set is dense in the cocountable topology. Instead you want the topology where the nonempty open sets are the sets whose complements have cardinality less than $2^\omega$.

You are right, @user14111. My bad. I assuming CH to prove that $d(X)=2^\omega$. Your example, taking sets whose complements have cardinality less than $2^\omega$, works without additional axioms.
